# List devices by IPs?

Tags: c#, sharppcap

How could I list the devices by IP instead of name ?

I am aware that I can get the device name and description but since I have many devices installed it would be rather easier if I could get it by IP to select one, but I couldnt find any option related so I am wondering if there is an approach to it ?

```
foreach (var dev in CaptureDeviceList.Instance)
{
    var str = String.Format("{0} {1}", dev.Name, dev.Description);
    iDeviceDropDown.Items.Add(str);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE, Found a solution:**

```
private void GetDevices()
{
    foreach (SharpPcap.LibPcap.LibPcapLiveDevice dev in SharpPcap.LibPcap.LibPcapLiveDeviceList.Instance)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dev.Addresses.Count; i++)
        {
            var ip = dev.Addresses[i].Addr.ipAddress;
            if (ip == null)
                continue;

            iDeviceDropDown.Items.Add(ip.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see there is a [`ICaptureDevice.MacAddress`](http://sharppcap.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=sharppcap/sharppcap;a=blob;f=SharpPcap/ICaptureDevice.cs;h=822a5c9f133ccc174bbdcd549f606c26694e5413;hb=22076350a040540471c684638cb22e02ee9dfa4b) property of type `System.Net.NetworkInformation.PhysicalAddress`. I don't think there is a direct way to get IP address from MAC Address but you can look it up using `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();`

Comment: actually I just found the solution to it using the LibPcap within SharpPcap.